# Snowflake split string into columns

Tags: split, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Hello I would like to split string with "-" into columns, and not have duplicate rows. So I expect to have two more new columns. Thank you

[image: Like this]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Can you provide a clearer example of the results you are looking for with the data laid out properly? (not just an image with markings on it)

Comment: i have tried lateral flattern and split - but split to table put the string data into new rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the maximum number of columns is known in advance [STRTOK_TO_ARRAY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/strtok_to_array.html) could be used:

```
SELECT STRTOK_TO_ARRAY(DELIVERY_ID, '|') AS arr
      ,arr[0]::string AS delivery_item_0
      ,arr[1]::string AS delivery_item_1
      ,arr[2]::string AS delivery_item_2
      ,arr[3]::string AS delivery_item_3
      --,...
FROM tab
```

Comment: This done the trick! Thank you very much :)

Comment: @saska Great to hear that :)